# Does TubeMate use some peer-to-peer network?

Tags: networking, tubemate

I was using TubeMate to download my first video with TubeMate, and I got banned from the Wi-Fi network I was using:

[image]

> Online activity through a browser or application has been flagged as malicious or in violation of the purpose of this network! Close all offending programs and try accessing the Internet again in five minutes.
>
> Quarantine Trigger
>
> "ET P2P ThunderNetwork UDP Traffic"(2009099) UDP 192.168.10.237:58509 -> 13.57.93.165:10050

According to https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/13.57.93.165, 13.57.93.165 is an Amazon.com IP. I have no idea why some packet would go there.

I'm wondering why TubeMate caused it. Does Tubemate use some peer-to-peer network? If not, what could have caused this ban?

Comment: Not sure by "peer-to-peer network", but based on the link, it's AWS (Amazon Web Service) Compute Engine. Not a user of TubeMate, but I'd assume just like most YouTube video downloader services, when you trigger the download, the app requests to the server on AWS to download and process the YouTube video first, then serve it back to the app from AWS for the device to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://community.ui.com/questions/IPS-Alert-1-Potential-Corporate-Privacy-Violation/b435dc41-7d47-4107-b789-198beee2c26d and https://redd.it/r0ok41, it looks like it was just a false positive. I'm guessing it was triggered by the port or IP.